# JupyterLab: Failed to load model class 'HBoxModel'

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, tqdm, jupyter-widget

I am using **JupyterLab** and trying to run `tqdm`. I've had an error persist for quite a while that seems to be a **`JS`** *error*.

Extensions:

```
Other labextensions (built into JupyterLab)
   app dir: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/share/jupyter/lab
        @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v5.0.3 enabled OK
        jupyter-leaflet v0.17.2 enabled OK
```

Error Message:

```
Failed to load model class 'VBoxModel' from module '@jupyter-widgets/controls'
Error: Module @jupyter-widgets/controls, version ^1.5.0 is not registered, however, 2.0.0 is
```

I have tried, re-installing, re-building all of the extensions listed above to no avail.

Comment: In general you should not need to rebuild jupyterlab. If you do, you are installing extensions the old way which may mean that you get incompatible versions. I would suggest creating a fresh environment with latest version of jupyterlab, ipwidgets and tqdm. If it works there, try to narrow down version differences and uninstall any manually installed jupyterlab extensions

Comment: this happened to me after upgrading jupyter lab to the latest version, but running a conda kernel with an older version of ipywidgets. Upgrading ipywidgets in the conda env did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue when upgrading to `jupyterlab==3.6.3`.

After upgrading ipywidgets to the at that time latest version `8.0.6`, it still failed. I managed to fix the issue by downgrading then to `ipywidgets==7.7.5`.